# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded (FLASK)

Tags: python, flask

**Hello .. i have a problem in Flask I have the following recursion code**
*`File "/Users/Desktop/Flask_Blog/flaskblog.py", line 20, in __repr__ return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')" [Previous line repeated 329 more times]*`

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '7f7c75dcec8tttcd1ckkaqq4bcf92b80'
app.config['SQLAlCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"
```

is there a solution

Comment: Please add details to the question specifying what you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

let us try to solve one issue in your code:

in order to get the value of a column like `self.username`, you should invoke the attribute `data` so the correct syntax become `self.username.data`

Therefore, correct `__repr__(self)` to

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username.data}', '{self.email.data}', '{self.image_file.data}')"
```